# Possible cause of frequent KeyErrors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, memcached

I’m getting KeyErrors while running Celery (both with v4.1.0 - latentcall and v4.4.7 - cliffs), using RabbitMQ v3.6.6 as the transport and memcached v1.4.33 as the backend. We’re running Python 2.7.13 on Debian 9, so, due to the Python version, Celery v4.4.7 is as high as we can go.

Sometimes Celery processing runs fine for a half-hour or so before we start seeing the KeyErrors. When they begin, they’re intermittent and other Celery tasks complete successfully. Sometimes the KeyErrors begin as soon as we kick off our processing.

This occurs both with letting memcached entries expire after 24 hours (the default) and setting the expiration time to 60 seconds (which we set to keep memcached memory usage in check in case it was using too much memory and purging keys that we still needed). In any case, even the 60-second expiration time wouldn’t explain the missing keys because the required processing on our workers always completes within a few seconds.

The keys are always GUIDs, e.g. KeyError: '40e9373c-5921-48c7-a5e5-94bf0c767682'
or KeyError: 'd89cc3a6-f7eea-41ec-bdc8-7023b3a5dbda'.

Where should we be looking for the cause of these errors? Could it be a bug in Celery’s handling of its keys or their storage?

Here's the error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myApp/parser.py", line 216, in parse
    resultSet = groupResultSet.get(timeout = timeoutInSeconds)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 635, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 753, in join_native
    acc[order_index[task_id]] = value
KeyError: '40e9373c-5921-48c7-a5e5-94bf0c767682'
```

Here's the code where I'm calling Celery's get():

```
logger.info("!!! About to form chunks")
groupResultSet = targetGroup.chunks([(target, targetData, numberOfNetworkErrors) for target in targets], 1).apply_async(queue=selectedQueue['name'])
logger.info("!!! Finished forming chunks")

timeoutInSeconds = 1800
logger.info("****** Before get() for {} ******".format(targetSubdomain))
resultSet = groupResultSet.get(timeout = timeoutInSeconds)
logger.info("****** Got resultSet for {} ******".format(targetSubdomain))
```

Comment: Where does this key error occurs in the code? is it in a library or in your code ? you should paste a stack trace if possible, this might help grealty to have an idea about what you are doing. Also, you might explain somehow what your worker should do, and why it might try to reach keys that does not exsits. As you present your issue , it looks like this is a specific to your project issue. I cannot help any further if I have no more context.

Comment: Sorry for omitting those details. Error occurs in Celery result.py while my application code waits on the get() call:

` Traceback (most recent call last):File “myApp/parser.py", line 216, in parse
    resultSet = groupResultSet.get(timeout = timeoutInSeconds)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 635, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/scraping/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 753, in join_native
    acc[order_index[task_id]] = value
KeyError: '40e9373c-5921-48c7-a5e5-94bf0c767682’ `

Comment: ok then, I put your trace in a more readable way here https://pastebin.com/bfKGNL4E .
Is it possible you to show the code around `“myApp/parser.py", line 216` by pasting a snippet in a past bin (or editing your question with a code section) ?
Is there in your code something that delete data in the structure where key error occurs. in your case you work with celery ; you might try to access to some ressources (event ?) that might have already been processed and is no longer available in celery over time / process?

Comment: Could it be that you use memcached as result backend, and you are getting those errors when you try to get results of an old task?

Comment: @utopman I've added both the traceback and the calling code to my question above. The keys in question are being handled solely by Celery and the structures being created by the workers are arrays that are initialized by the worker and passed back to the caller, so there's nothing we're doing that would be interfering with the keys.

Comment: @DejanLekic We _are_ using memcached as the backend. The worker processes run in under 10 seconds, and we are getting these KeyErrors with a 60-second expiration set in memcached and with the default 24-hour expiration in memcached. So it's quite perplexing why these keys aren't being found.